# Is it possible to precisely center Masonry.js content?

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

I am trying to build a layout of one to four columns - variable per page designed on, with the Masonry plugin. So far I've liked how it works.

However, it's leaving a highly annoying gap that with the configurations I cannot seem to get rid of.

To point out - it's already centered on the page. However, within the centered block, the content appears left justified.

[image: Masonry problem example]

The inner content has no margins either. Masonry is being initialized as:

```
$('.msgblock').masonry({
      columnWidth: '.grid-item',
      gutter: 8,
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      fitWidth: true,
      resize: false
});
```

I have eliminated the .msgblock width entirely in CSS, so it is being provided by the plugin.

```
.msgblock {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.grid-item {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the flex method:

```
.grid-item {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**Update:** to fill the gap you can use the `stretch` option. Here's a fiddle

```css
.grid-item {
  background: ghostwhite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 200px;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  outline: 1px solid #dde;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: ghostwhite;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #eef;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid-item" style='min-width:60%'>Cell 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style='min-width:35%'>Cell 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style='min-width:45%'>Cell 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style='min-width:25%'>Cell 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style='min-width:15%'>Cell 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No luck - the rightmost gap is still present and adding content to one, the other block was... squashed. It ignored the block width property (dynamically assigned, but still no margin/padding)

Comment: Will you use equal height row content? Or they would be masonry like too?

Comment: I am laying out a grid of columns, but within the columns the content can be variable height.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing, I've decided to go with the CSS Flexbox property. It does what I need to do without as much hassle as Masonry, and my browser support planing goes back for IE 11 - so it should be a better choice. Doing this also eliminates some JS load from the system.